# SQL Update One Table with Value from Another Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL statement -

```
SELECT e.*, i.CaseNo, c.Claimant, c.Defendant, c.ClientID
FROM tblExpenses AS e
INNER JOIN tblInvoices AS i ON e.InvNo = i.InvNo
INNER JOIN tblCases AS c ON i.CaseNo = c.CaseNo
```

which demonstrates the link between three tables.

`tblInvoices` has a primary key `[InvNo]` which is also a foreign key in `tblExpenses` thus linking each expense with the relevant invoice.

`tblCases` has a primary key `[CaseNo]` which is also a foreign key in `tblInvoices`, thereby linking each invoice to a particular case.

Finally each case in `tblCases` has a column called `[ClientID]` which identifies the client whom the invoice was sent to.

Now then, `tblExpenses` also has a foreign key `[ClientID]` but at present the column is not populated. What I want to do, is use the above links to populate `[ClientID]` in `tblExpenses`, with the `[ClientID]` from `tblCases`, via the aforementioned links.

However I am unclear how to rewrite my `SELECT` query in order to carry out this population of the `[ClientID]` column in `tblExpenses`.

Can anyone please assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the sufficient select query to get the required information. You just need to convert it to an update query.

```
UPDATE e SET e.ClientID=c.ClientID
FROM tblExpenses AS e
INNER JOIN tblInvoices AS i ON e.InvNo = i.InvNo
INNER JOIN tblCases AS c ON i.CaseNo = c.CaseNo
```